# applying xml to xslt help

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that is very long, but here is a shot excerpt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dicom>
    <attr tag="00020000" vr="UL" len="4">190</attr>
    <attr tag="00020001" vr="OB" len="2">00\01</attr>
    <attr tag="00020002" vr="UI" len="30">1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.88.11</attr>
    <attr tag="00080090" vr="PN" len="14">Roberts^^^Dr.^</attr>
</dicom>
```

I also have an xslt file that is also very long, but here is an excerpt.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml-fo" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <!-- the stylesheet processing entry point -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dicom"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dicom">
        TEST
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="attr[@tag='00080090']"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have two questions.
1.  When I apply the xml to the xslt, I don't get any output.  After testing it appears that the dicom template is never even getting called.  Why is this?
2.  If I change the matching criteria for the dicom template from "dicom" to "/", then it does get called, but the variable is not being set correctly.

I know it won't produce valid XML, I'm just trying to figure out what's going on, and what's wrong with my understanding of xslt.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What XSLT engine are you using? By the way, you would apply the XSLT to the XML input document (and not vice versa), maybe there is some misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample works for me.

Please note that if the template matching `/` is simply doing an `xsl:apply-templates` on `dicom` you actually don't need it as there is already a built-in template that will be matched automatically doing exactly the same.